# Reducing distance between two images placed side by side using minipage

Tags: minipage

Can someone explain me how I can manually control the distance between two images that are placed side-by-side using minipage?

I tried to use \hspace{-0.5cm} but it doesn't seem to work.

This is how I include the images currently:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{cc}  
\hspace{-0.5cm}
      \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=6.0cm]{images/result1}
      \end{minipage} 
 &
 \hspace{-0.1cm}
      \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=6.0cm]{images/result2}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}      
  \vspace{0.1cm}
  \caption{results}
\end{figure}
```

I tried to modify both `[width=6.0cm]` and `{0.5\textwidth}`, but I'm never able to get a real thin margin between both images. If I omit the `tabular` environment the margin becomes narrower but then the images are not centered anymore but stick to the left border of the page.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried to do?  What does “doesn’t seem to work” mean?

Comment: minipage adds no space, so the spacing is just exactly the same as the space between two letters `x\hspace{1cm}x` has 1cm between the x and the same space if you replace the x by minipages

Comment: The minipage are not needed at all and the space is from the padding around table cells which you had not mentioned at all in your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither the table nor nthe minipages are needed,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}%
\hspace{.25cm}%
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}%

\caption{two images .25cm apart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a nice short solution. Too bad that most of the solutions one finds upon googling look much more intrecate and involve minipage etc.